# Handle React errors via Sentry wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sentry

I've used the example from sentry docs as described here https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/react/#error-boundaries

(Except since I don't need fallback view - I've used just `<Sentry.ErrorBoundary>` without additional options.)

It works - I see the errors appearing in Sentry dashboard. What I want to improve here is to avoid seeing errors from the main webpage scope and only receive errors that have happened inside my React application boundaries (and it's Redux and axios handlers). Is it possible?

I've also found that you can use something like   `ignoreErrors: [ "top.GLOBALS", ],` (https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/) But still if I add a simple error producer like that: `document.addEventListener('click', ()=>{notExistingFunction()});` - and click on the page somewhere outside my app - I get the error tracked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tiny note in the [react error boundary docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/components/errorboundary/) which states:

> In development mode, React will rethrow errors caught within an error boundary. This will result in errors being reported twice to Sentry with the above setup, but this won’t occur in your production build.

I have to presume that this is so that developers receive rich stack traces during development. This doesn't answer our question about whether it is configurable (it doesn't appear to be), which is disappointing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but these errors come from production environment:(